# Can I use Babel to transpile both ECMA and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs, babel-register

I have a simple project with 2 tests.

```
test.jsx
test.tsx
```

When I run mocha with the following presets

```
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
```

The jsx test works but the tsx has a problem parsing...

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from
'react';
                                                                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

When I change to...

```
"presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-react"],
```

I get

```
I:\...\enzyme-example-mocha\test\.setup.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { JSDOM } f
rom 'jsdom';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Is there a way I can get both to work? My project is based off of

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/tree/master/packages/enzyme-example-mocha

I also tried

```
["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
```

But I get the same...

```
I:\...\enzyme-example-mocha\test\.setup.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { JSDOM } f
rom 'jsdom';
```

If I switch around `["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-react"]` I get

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from
'react';
                                                                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Do you have an issue if you enable both presets?

Comment: yeah which ever is not the right way and comes first it breaks. Thanks for reminding me I will add some